# name 'List' is not defined-Python

Tags: python

I get this error when I run the code.How can I fix?

```
class Solution:    
def uniqueOccurrences(self, arr: List[int]) -> bool:
    d, counts = {}, {}
    for n in arr:
        if n in d: d[n] += 1
        else: d[n] = 1

    for k in d:
        if d[k] in counts: return False
        else: counts[d[k]] = 0

    return True
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Import it:

```
from typing import List
```